# How to count unique values from predefined range of rows from a 3rd column in a file

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I have tsv file containing 8 column and 10000 rows. I need to take unique count of values at every 1000 rows interval from column 7.
Please suggest the  linux commands to get desired output. I tried following command but it did not work:

```
awk >myfile 'NR>=1&&NR<=1000' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: In the title you write _3rd column_, in the text body _column 7_; you'd have to make up your mind.

Comment: Can you show us what `myfile` looks like, show the result of your command, and explain the expected output?

Comment: I want unique count from any given column ( 1 to 8) for interval of every 10000 rows. The expected outcome would be - 1 to 10000 - 300 uniq count, 1 to 20000 - 400 uniq count and so on till last row of that column